# Allowing XMLHTTPRequest on Azure Server

Tags: jquery, azure, xmlhttprequest, swagger-2.0

I am trying to deploy Swagger-UI on my Azure Server. It works fine in loading the json file but when I try to access the api commands on the Swagger API page I get this error:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://webhostname.azurewebsites.net/swagger/#/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/pet/findByStatus?status=sold'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

This is what my web.config file looks like:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="pythonpath" value="%SystemDrive%\home\site\wwwroot" />
    <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="hostingstart-python.application" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".syx" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".tab" mimeType="text/plain" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
    </staticContent>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,DELETE,HEAD,PUT,OPTIONS" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Olaround-Debug-Mode, Authorization, Accept" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Expose-Headers" value="X-Olaround-Debug-Mode, X-Olaround-Request-Start-Timestamp, X-Olaround-Request-End-Timestamp, X-Olaround-Request-Time, X-Olaround-Request-Method, X-Olaround-Request-Result, X-Olaround-Request-Endpoint" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Loading over https:// doesn't work either

Comment: Well the error is pretty self-explanatory. Load petstore resource over `https` not `http`

Comment: @Zealander Loading over https:// doesn't work either

Comment: What error are you getting this time?

Comment: Looks like when you load `https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/pet/findByStatus?status=sold` directly in the browser, it switches back to `http`. Looks like either swagger API does support `https` or you need a secure API key to utilize `https` feature. Can you load your website on Azure over `http`? The problem is that your protocols have to be the same. Be it `http` or `https`